# How to introduce time out pop up on lighting aura component

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, javascript

I have developed a lightning aura component for import and export. If user opens the component page and not performed any thing for longer time (example:5 min) and then tried to access the component data then i want to show some pop up saying session time out need to refresh the page message. If user clicks on ok then page should get reloaded. I thought of using connectedcallback in rederrer. Please suggest how can i do it or is there any other way to do it.

Component page:

[image]

Comment: Are you using a visualforce page with lightningOut or direct Lightning aura component?

Comment: Direct lightning aura component.